# Derivative Chain Rule $f(x) = (3x^2+2)^2 (x^2 -5x)^3$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm learning chain rule in derivative, 
and I don't understand this in the example.

$$f(x) = (3x^2+2)^2 (x^2 -5x)^3\\$$
\begin{align}
f'(x)&= (3x^2 +2)^2[3(x^2 -5x)^2(2x-5)] + (x^2-5x)^3[2(3x^2+2)(6x)]
\\&=3(3x^2 +2)(x^2-5x)^2[(3x^2+2)(2x-5)+4x(x^2-5x)]
\\&= 3(3x^2 +2)(x^2-5x)^2[6x^3-15x^2+4x-10+4x^3-20x^2]
\\&=3(3x^2+2)(x^2-5x)^2(10x^3-35x^2+4x-10)
\end{align}

I understand the first line, because they just applied the chain rule,

but I don't understand the second line. I think they are simplifying it, but still I don't understand.

Could anyone explain what happened there? or add extra steps so it's easier??

Comment: In the first line of your work, the first term is good, but there is an error in your second term.

Comment: Namely, the derivative of $(3x+2)^2$ is $2(3x+2)(3)$, not $2(3x^2+2)(6x)$.

Comment: Oh, this is one of example in my book, I just don't understand what happened

Comment: Is it $f(x) = (3x^{\color{red} 2}+2)^2(x^2 - 5x)^3$?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that @AaronMaroja

Comment: You missed a square on the title as well.

Comment: Wait, it's not my fault, the book's question do not have a square, but in the solution there is @AaronMaroja

Comment: Then is either a typo or a different function. And of course a different answer would follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Put $(x^2- 5x)^2$, $(3x^2 + 2)$ and $3$ in evidence. Then

$$\begin{align}f'(x)&= \color{green}{(3x^2 + 2)}^2[\color{red} 3\color {#05f}{(x^2 - 5x)^2} (2x - 5)] + \color {#05f}{(x^2 - 5x)^3}[2\color{green}{(3x^2 + 2)}\color {red} 6 x]\\&=\color{red}3\color{green}{(3x^2 + 2)}\color{#05f}{ (x^2 - 5x)^2} \,[(3x^2 + 2)(2x - 5) + 4x (x^2 - 5)]\end{align}$$

Comment: Will you take it up a bit further please?

Comment: One more step..

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
f'(x) &= (3x^2 +2)^2[3(x^2 -5x)^2(2x-5)] + (x^2-5x)^3[2(3x+2)(3)]\\
&=3(3x^2+2)(x^2-5x)^2[(2x-5)-(x^2-5x)(2)] \\
&=3(3x^2+2)(x^2-5x)^2[2x-5-4x^2+10x] \\
&=3(3x^2+2)(x^2-5x)^2(-4x^2+12x-5)
\end{align}

Comment: A small tip: A proof is not a list of formulas, but a series of carefully explained formulas with notes to help the reader.